# How to solve [-Wunused-but-set-variable] error of kernel compiling?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile linux kernel "linux-2.6.37.3". After writing the command "make -j4" I am getting error below:

```
>drivers/scsi/sym53c8xx_2/sym_hipd.c:5490:18: warning: variable ‘lp’ set but not used > [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>  LD [M]  drivers/scsi/qla4xxx/qla4xxx.o
>  CC [M]  drivers/scsi/sym53c8xx_2/sym_nvram.o
>  LD [M]  drivers/scsi/sym53c8xx_2/sym53c8xx.o
>  make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You posted what looks like a compile time warning and not the real compile error :) probably  the real error is just few line up the console output

Comment: Try running `make` again but without the `-j4` flag so that the output is easier to follow.